# Natural expression for "Parking space" in Japanese

Tags: daily-life

I'm looking for one or more natural ways to say "parking space" in Japanese.

Here are a few candidates I've found via search and other means, but I'd like to know what people in Japan actually use on a daily basis.

> スペース
>
> 駐車スペース
>
> 余裕 (?)

Without knowing this word I could probably just say "この駐車場にはとまるところがないね", but I'd like to know a more specific expression for this.

Comment: `とまるところがないね` -> You meant to type と**め**るところがない? (とまるところがない sounds like you have no place to [泊]{と}まる)

Comment: I thought that とまる would also apply to cars stopping (ex: 車がとまった), am I wrong? I guess the problem is transitive vs intransitive.

Comment: Exactly. And that's why kanji are a beautiful thing anyway (止まる vs 泊まる in this case), as even if you make a grammatical mistake at least what you mean is (hopefully) clear.

Comment: Only 「とめる」 is correct for the context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

駐車場 is a *parking lot*, a dedicated area for parking cars. Users are often charged hourly, daily or monthly.

If you want to refer to a individual parking space in a 駐車場, or a "space to park a car" in general (such as road shoulders), you can simply say **（車を）駐【と】める場所**.

駐 is a kanji used for this purpose (to park). There are also 車を止【と】める (to stop a running car, eg, taxi) and 車を停【と】める (to stop a car, eg, at a red light). If you're not sure, it's safe to stick to hiragana.

> - この駐車場には、もう車をとめる場所がない。　＝　この駐車場は満車だ。
> - 駐車場がないので、他にとめる場所を探そう。

I think 駐車（する）スペース is equally OK, too.

By the way, [パーキングエリア](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2) is 和製英語 and refers to rest areas / rest stops along highways.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience here in Japan the most used phrase is 駐車場.  I have not heard anyone use the above mentioned phrases or words.

If you wanted to express not being able to park somewhere like in your example sentence,

> この駐車場にはとまるところがないね。

a more common way to say it would be

> ここ空いていないね。

Or inversely describe that the carpark is full by saying:

> この駐車場は満{まん}車｛しゃ｝になっているよ。

If you want to stick closer to your example sentence you could just shorten the sentence a bit and like l'électeur said, change the verb to とめる and conjugate it in the 可能形 (potential) form.

> ここにはとめれない。

Obviously if you need to make these examples more polite just conjugate and add respective polite forms where they are needed.

Comment: Interesting, from what you are saying there is no single word that is used to mean "parking space", since 駐車場 would represent the entire lot. But I guess based on the sentences you give, there is no need for such a word.

Comment: `とめれない` -> 意図的に「とめ**ら**れない」を避けて、ら抜き言葉にされたのでしょうか… @Locksleyu カジュアル・口語的な表現でよければ、「(ここ、)とめるとこ ないねー / とめっとこ ないねー」(←ここは、とめるところがないね) とか、「とめらんないねー / とめれないねー」(←とめられないね) とか「(ここ、)いっぱいだねー」などもよく聞かれると思います。

Comment: @lock There are always many different ways to say the same thing.  I also happen to work in the car industry off and on and sometimes while driving around looking for a park people will just shorten the phrase down to just the verb.  駐めれねー or 駐めれないっすね.  Everything is context based in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Closest I can think of...

> **車をとめるとこ**

```
a place to park (a) car - a parking space
```

This doesn't always refer to a "space in a parking lot", but definitely is a very common way to refer to one.

> 駐車場では**車をとめるとこ**がなかった。

```
"There weren't any spaces left in the parking lot."
```

Answer (score 2):

I've also asked this question to native Japanese speakers and the answer was a bit ambiguous.

As far as I understand they will either use:

> 空いているところ
>
> とまるところ

I also asked how they would refer to parking stall number and they said they would just use the number.

> 駐車場の２１番に…

Answer (score 1):

My Japanese friend right next to me said it's 駐車スペース, but that she doesn't say or hear it very often.

You'd be surprised at the things for which names are well-known in English, but no one around me can name in Japanese. Although she came up with this one in a moment, this may be one of those words. For example, I've yet to talk to one Japanese person who knows the word for "roadblock".